# How to prevent submit script from textarea input

Tags: javascript

how can I prevent submitting only script to the database, but all HTML tags should be allowed using the following script I'm using. Please help.

```
<form name="exthtmlForm" style="height: 100%;">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Source Editor</legend>
    <div id="editor" name="editor" style="height: 100%;">
      <textarea id="iExthtml" style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: 50px; box-sizing: border-box;">
        <?php if($exthtml_content!=""){ echo htmlentities($exthtml_content, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); } ?>
      </textarea>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>

$(document).on('click','#abtSubmit',function(){
  var data = $('#iExthtml').val().replace(/'/g, "\\'");
  dataString=$('form[name=exthtmlForm]').serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<?php echo $GLOBALS['base_url'];?>ajax/cpanel/cpanel-ajax.php?mode=UpdateExthtml",
    cache: false,
    data: { content : data , dpid : <?php echo $dpid; ?> , menuID : <?php echo $MPage; ?> },  
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      if(data.success == "yes"){
        if($("#states").length!==1){
          $(".error_2525").remove();
          $('#abtSubmit').before("<div class='error_2525' id='success_message' style='margin-top: 10px;'>Content updated successfully</div>");
          $('#success_message').delay(5000).fadeOut(300, function(){
            $('#success_message').remove();
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Where is your code that needs editing regarding the stripping of script tags. 

I would highly recommend not doing this with `JavaScript` (clientside) but serverside with `PHP`.

Comment: Also I can't make heads or tales out of this code.

Comment: Any client-side validation is purely for the convenience of the user, and it should never be used to sanitize user input.  You need to strip out malicious input on the server.

Comment: Hi Mouser, thanks for your comments. Please suggest how to accomplish stripping scripts using server side PHP code.

Comment: $input = $_POST['content'];
 function cleanInput($input) {
     $search = array(
      '@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si',   // Strip out javascript
    );
     $output = preg_replace($search, '', $input);
     return $output;
 }
 $val = cleanInput($input);

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to accomplish this. First, you need to pull the default value for the textarea and store it in a javascript variable

```
jQuery(document.ready(function(){
    window.form_exthtmlForm_default = '<?php echo (($exthtml_content!="") ? htmlentities($exthtml_content, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') : ""); ?>';
}));
```

Then you need to use this variable (`window.form_exthtmlForm_default`) on submit to insure that the form is not passing the default value.

Revised submit function:

```
$(document).on('click','#abtSubmit',function(){
  var data = $('#iExthtml').val().replace(/'/g, "\\'");

  //Here we will return false if the form has the default textarea value.    
  if ($('#iExthtml').val() == window.form_exthtmlForm_default) {
      //You would want to also provide some sort of frontend 
      //user message to alert the user to populate the text
      return false;
  }

  dataString=$('form[name=exthtmlForm]').serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<?php echo $GLOBALS['base_url'];?>ajax/cpanel/cpanel-ajax.php?mode=UpdateExthtml",
    cache: false,
    data: { content : data , dpid : <?php echo $dpid; ?> , menuID : <?php echo $MPage; ?> },  
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      if(data.success == "yes"){
        if($("#states").length!==1){
          $(".error_2525").remove();
          $('#abtSubmit').before("<div class='error_2525' id='success_message' style='margin-top: 10px;'>Content updated successfully</div>");
          $('#success_message').delay(5000).fadeOut(300, function(){
            $('#success_message').remove();
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```